# ObservableCollection without LINQ MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
public ObservableCollection<User> GetProducts()
    {    

       // hasError = false;
        ObservableCollection<User> products = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        try
        {
            LinqDataContext dc = new LinqDataContext();
            var query = from q in dc.LinqProducts
                select new SqlProduct
                {
                    Login = q.Login,
                    Password = q.Password,
                    Permission = q.ModelName,
                    LockedAccount = q.LockedAccount,

                };
            foreach (SqlProduct sp in query)
                products.Add(sp.SqlProduct2Product());
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return products;

    }
```

as newbie as this may sound, I'm unable to find anything about loading a DataGrid from SQL (on MVVM). The only thing I've found is the code above from codeproject. The whole project works but I'm not familiar with LINQ so I want to do it with SQL Queries instead. I'm trying to edit this to select everything from my USER table and display it.

Comment: SQL Queries you mean ado net?

Comment: if you want sql queries - then use sql queries. DataGrid should not be aware where data comes from originally. All that DataGrid needs is ItemsSource collection which is filled somehow

Comment: @SeM Not necessarily, an SqlDataAdapter or something.

Comment: @ASh That's the thing, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Abdou, start with writing a query. Then make sure you can invoke in from app *somewhere* and get data. then integrate working data-access code into MVVM architecture

Comment: `the whole project works but I'm not familiar with LINQ so I want to do it with SQL Queries instead` this my friend is defeatist, lazy, and just plain XY. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem